# google map like search on wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

[image: google map search]

I want this kind of search on my wordpress site. I m using wpestate wordpress theme. Anybody has any idea about this?? Exactly the same..Any plugin or custom code???Or js,jquery??

How do i embed this kind of search in my wordpress site??

Comment: what do you mean by `I want this kind of search on my wordpress site.`?  If I guess you are asking about **autocomplete**

Comment: yes....I want to know how do i implement that on my wordpress site??

Comment: You can simple include [jQuery UI's autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) and check this question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/40719